# Read pallet state using Metamask

Tags: pallet, evm, metamask

I would like to read the state of a pallet using web3 clients (Metamask, Truffle). Let's suppose the pallet has exposed the function `getValue()`.

I have not installed either EVM and Ethereum pallet because I don't need to be fully EVM compatible.

I was thinking about the following flow as a possible approach:

```
1
+------------------------+
| Web3 Client            |
| (Metamask, Truffle)    |
+------------------------+
           |
2          v
+------------------------+
| Server implements      |
| EVM JSON-RPC           |
+------------------------+
           |
3          v
+------------------------+
| RPC Substrate Client   |
+------------------------+
           |
4          v
+------------------------+
| Substrate Node         |
+------------------------+
```

**1.** The Web3 client would perform the reading request. In this step, I would also need to implement the `getValue()` function in Solidity so it could be called from the client, as it needs the ABI to perform the request.
**2.** The RPC Server would implement the endpoint, so the request would be redirected when `getValue()` was instantiated.
**3.** The Substrate RPC client would connect to the Substrate node.
**4.** The Substrate node would return the result.

Does this approach make sense? Is there something similar that has already been implemented? Or is there any library that I could use?

Comment: Interested in doing something similar, have you made any progress?

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas unfortunately I did not continue down this path and decided to add the full EVM layer as a stopgap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be amazing to have this. As far as I know there is no implementation about that yet. But I know there is a discussion on the Polkadot Forum that you should check: [WrappedEVM Eth RPC compatibility layer](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/wrappedevm-eth-rpc-compatibility-layer/2775).